# Unable to reload javascript cache even after versioning

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a versioned JS file, in my asp.net mvc application, whose version changes everytime I change the version of the application - rather simple approach.

Now, it has been a while since I made any changes to the script, so when I recently had to do it, I noticed that the browser is not taking the newer code.

I have tested it out in chrome and IE, but to no gain.

My .cshtml includes the js file at the end like so

```
<script src="~/Scripts/app/xyzFile.js?@version"></script>
```

The `@version` takes the value from the `web.config`

What I find to be even more peculiar is that the Sources tab in the Chrome Developer tools shows me the new code, but the application still works like the old code.
The part of the JS file that I am concerned with is like this

```
var mySelectionChanged = function (e) {
    debugger;
    if ($('.myDiv').val() == "0") {
        //do something
    }
    else if ($('.myDiv').val() == "-1") {
        //do something
    }
    else {
        //do something
    }
};

$('.myDiv').change(mySelectionChanged);
```

Prior to the change, it was just an `if...else`. The app is still using the `if...else` logic. I checked the value of `mySelectionChanged` in Chrome's and IE's Console and they both resulted showing the old code, but like I previously mentioned, the Source tab in Chrome shows the new code.

I have tried changing the `@version` to be many things, removed it even, but the outcome remains the same.

Comment: so hard refresh to blow away the cache.

Comment: Ctrl+F5? Done. Cleared browser history too. Changed the name of the function, but the new name is unrecognisable

Comment: Does that method exist in another file?

Comment: Yes. It is a seperate JS file